# Failed getting current site subscription id using context uri: in sharepoint while try to redirect to new page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Failed getting current site subscription id using context uri: in sharepoint while try to redirect to new page

I have an Excel button designed to download an Excel template. When I click the button, it generates the Excel file and redirects to a new page for the download. While this functionality works seamlessly on my testing server, upon deploying to the production server, an error occurs with the message: 'Failed getting the current site subscription ID using context URI.

string _navURL = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_layouts/15/Accred/Provider/ShowReportExcel.aspx?_fileName=" + _filename;

```
            string _script = "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" + "window.open('" + _navURL + "');\n" + "</script>\n";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", _script, false);
```

Comment: Are you using claims-based authentication? Are you working with SharePoint Add-ins? Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/claims-authentication-does-not-validate-user  

And: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/troubleshoot-issues-with-sharepoint-hosted-add-ins/ba-p/510086

and let me know if this helps or provide more info on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Failed getting current site subscription id using context uri" in SharePoint typically indicates an issue with retrieving the current site subscription ID. This can occur when trying to access certain context properties or information related to the SharePoint site.